# Upload files to site automatically without browser focus

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, headless, katalon-studio

I work on test script to automate file uploading to a site and execute script in headless mode. It needs to upload list of files one by one, I develop it based on `Selenium WebDriver`. I use `AutoIT` script to handle dialog window, file chooser window. Parameter `$CmdLine[1]` contains the path of actual file.

```
ControlFocus("Open a file","","Edit1")
ControlSetText("Open a file","","Edit1", $CmdLine[1])
ControlClick("Open a file","","Button1")
```

It is executed with this code:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(autoITExecutable);
```

It opens dialog window, so it can't work without focus on browser window. `java.awt.Robot` class works similar, it needs focus on browser window.

I tried to use `sendKeys()` method too, but input field is unable to handle file in this way. `Katalon Studio` is also unable to handle this field.

Example sites with similar forms:

http://ajaxuploader.com/demo/simple-upload.aspx

https://ec.europa.eu/cefdigital/DSS/webapp-demo/validation

https://tus.io/demo.html

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code:

```
// wait for the window to appear
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());

// switch to the file upload window
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();

// enter the filename
alert.sendKeys(fileName);

// hit enter
Robot r = new Robot();
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

// switch back
driver.switchTo().activeElement();
```

Comment: I see, but if file chooser window is not opened, there is no place to paste file path.

Comment: When you click on ‘Choose File’ button, OS native file select dialog will be opened. This dialog will not be recognized by your driver, so when uploading any file in Selenium you should never click on ‘Choose File’ button. Instead, just use sendkeys to select the file,

WebElement El = driver.findElement(By.id("'fileUploadField'"));
El.sendKeys("c:\\temp\\abc.txt");

Comment: It doesn't work for me for these sites. Could you please show a working example? Maybe for this site: ec.europa.eu/cefdigital/DSS/webapp-demo/validation ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one,

```
webElement.sendKeys(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "file path");
```

Here,

- webElement is your element identified for file upload. Please make sure that the input element is visible.
- try to specify file path as relative path of the content that we want to upload.

Make sure, you are not clicking on the browse button, clicking on browse button will open windows dialogue box where selenium webDriver will won't work.

Comment: For which element should I send the file? Could you please show an example? Maybe for this site: https://ec.europa.eu/cefdigital/DSS/webapp-demo/validation ?

Answer (score 0):

Use Selenium directly:

`driver().findElement(By.id("ContentPlaceHolder1_Uploader1__Insert")).sendKeys(pathToFile);`

With this you can avoid to use the system dependend dialog.

Comment: Yes, I tried it already, but it is not working in case of this field, as I mentioned in my question.

Comment: Then I didn't get your question, what is wrong with the AutoIt code? Did you escape the AutoIT reserved characters? You can also use `Send($CmdLine[1])`

Comment: You may also try to use plain Javascript from within Selenium: `driver.executeScript("document.querySelector('input#myId').files = new Array('"+pathToFile+"')";`

Comment: AutoIT is working, but needs browser focus, not suitable to execute it in headless mode or simply without focus on browser.

Comment: Could you please show a working example? Maybe for this site: ec.europa.eu/cefdigital/DSS/webapp-demo/validation ?